# Showidx gives "Undefined control sequence" error

Tags: imakeidx, undefined

The following MWE with `showidx` and `imakeidx`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{showidx}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
Test\index{xxxx}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

generates the error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \ifdefequal 
      {\imki@jobname }{\@idxfile }{}{[\@idxfile ]\space }xxxx
l.6 Test\index{xxxx}
```

TeXstudio with MiKTeX and Overleaf both give the same message.

**Edit**: I did a fresh install a few weeks ago. The log file reports the following version numbers:

```
("C:\Users\Joe\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\showidx.sty"
Package: showidx 2014/09/29 v1.0m Standard LaTeX package
\indexbox=\insert199
)
("C:\Users\Joe\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/imakeidx\imakeidx.st
y"
Package: imakeidx 2016/10/15 v1.3e Package for typesetting indices in a synchro
nous mode
```

Comment: Hmm, you also need `etoolbox`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
```

and report it to @egreg:-)

Comment: This works! Thank you, and egreg.

Comment: @JosephQuinsey oh it's just that `imakeindex` uses the command `\ifdefequal` which is defined in the `etoolbox` package, but it doesn't load that package. egreg will no doubt change imakeindex to either load etoolbox or write the test a different way

Comment: The problem, I think, is with `showidx`?

Comment: @JosephQuinsey no it is `imakeidx` that uses `\ifdefequal` without defining it, so we can quite happily blame egreg (but he'll fix it I'm sure)

Comment: @JosephQuinsey look at line 175 of imakeidx.sty